# Nginx, как сделать прокси "необязательным"?

Tags: nginx

Имею такой конфиг:

```
location /adminer {
    proxy_pass http://adminer:8080;
}
```

Сделал deploy на `production`, и пришел к выводу, что в `adminer` необходимости нет. Выключил его а в конфиге оставил. Nginx не запускается, так-как `adminer` выключен.

Не очень хочется удалять / комментировать в конфигах на тот случай, если понадобится доступ к бд.

**Как его оставить? Можно ли в nginx указать этот proxy как "необязательный"?**

Comment: Что значит «выключил»? Если вы имеете в виду, что удалили upstream adminer, но при этом оставили его упоминания в активном location, то конечно же такой конфиг будет некорректным

Comment: Нет, upstream там нет. Развернут в докере, `adminer` - имя контейнера, как хост вместо ip. Выключил остановив контейнер.

Comment: тут должно просто 502 выдавать. нгинкс запускается в таких конфигурациях. ищите проблему в логе чтоль)

Comment: Так вот круто было бы! Но получаю `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "adminer" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf:49`. Upstream-ов нет в конфиге вообще, тем более на `adminer`.

Comment: В таком случае nginx должен отказываться запускаться даже если контейнер был бы включен

Comment: Может быть и должен, но стоит написать `docker-compose -f adminer.yml up`, как все работает: https://i.imgur.com/hVn2iUT.png

Comment: Прикольное явление: если nginx осиливает преобразовать имя хоста в ip-адрес, то он использует его как есть, а если не осиливает, то считает его названием upstream и жалуется на его отсутствие. Даже не знаю, как это обойти

Comment: На enSO предлагают костыль через переменную https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
location /adminer {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set $upstream_adminer adminer;
    proxy_pass http://$upstream_adminer:8080;
}
```

Спасибо [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)